# Tensorflow hashtable lookup with arrays

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to get `HashMap` type of functionality to work with tensorflow. I got it to work when keys and values are of `int` type. But when they are arrays it gives error - `ValueError: Shapes (2,) and () are not compatible` on line `default_value)`

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


input_tensor = tf.constant([1, 1], dtype=tf.int64)
keys = tf.constant(np.array([[1, 1],[2, 2],[3, 3]]),  dtype=tf.int64)
values = tf.constant(np.array([[4, 1],[5, 1],[6, 1]]),  dtype=tf.int64)
default_value = tf.constant(np.array([1, 1]),  dtype=tf.int64)

table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(
        tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(keys, values),
        default_value)

out = table.lookup(input_tensor)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    table.init.run()
    print(out.eval())
```

Comment: `default_value` should be a scalar value, not an array.

Comment: But my values are arrays. How would that make sense? And it also gives error: `ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'key_value_init_4' (op: 'InitializeTable') with input shapes: [2], [3,2], [3,2].`

Comment: I've upvoted just because @MihkelL. actually posted an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it's so refreshing! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable`](http://tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable) only works with one dimensional tensors. Here's an implementation with [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor)s, which of course only works if your keys are integer (int32 or int64) tensors.

For the values I'm storing the two columns in two separate tensors, but if you have many columns, you might want to just store them in a large tensor, and store the indices as values in one [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor).

This code (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

lookup = tf.placeholder( shape = ( 2, ), dtype = tf.int64 )
default_value = tf.constant( [ 1, 1 ], dtype = tf.int64 )
input_tensor = tf.constant( [ 1, 1 ], dtype=tf.int64)
keys = tf.constant( [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ],  dtype=tf.int64 )
values = tf.constant( [ [ 4, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ] ],  dtype=tf.int64 )
val0 = values[ :, 0 ]
val1 = values[ :, 1 ]

st0 = tf.SparseTensor( keys, val0, dense_shape = ( 7, 7 ) )
st1 = tf.SparseTensor( keys, val1, dense_shape = ( 7, 7 ) )

x0 = tf.sparse_slice( st0, lookup, [ 1, 1 ] )
y0 = tf.reshape( tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense( x0, default_value = default_value[ 0 ] ), () )
x1 = tf.sparse_slice( st1, lookup, [ 1, 1 ] )
y1 = tf.reshape( tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense( x1, default_value = default_value[ 1 ] ), () )

y = tf.stack( [ y0, y1 ], axis = 0 )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( y, feed_dict = { lookup : [ 1, 2 ] } ) )
    print( sess.run( y, feed_dict = { lookup : [ 1, 1 ] } ) )
```

will output:

> [4 1]
>   [1 1]

as desired (looks up the value ***[ 4, 1 ]*** for the key ***[ 1, 2 ]*** and the default value ***[ 1, 1 ]*** for ***[ 1, 1 ]***, which points to a non-existent entry.)

Comment: Yeah but since the key doesn't exist in the HashTable it should return `default_value`. So this isn't a working solution. This reshaping doesn't work for many example. If you think about it, it doesn't leave the logic working as it would be hashmap. for example if you change the keys list to `[[1, 2],[1, 1],[5, 6]]` it should work - in normal hashtable implementations- but it throws an error with your solution. :)

Comment: Oh you're right, haven't thought this through apparently. Let me think if I can come up with something else. Do we know anything about the contents of the indices tensors, e.g., are they integer, or have a max value? That would help a lot.

Comment: Rewrote the answer with `tf.SparseTensor`s.